# Double not in if condition - best practice?

Tags: java, if-statement, logical-operators

I'm still kind of a newbie so your wisdom and advice would be appreciated.

I've got a tricky if condition and I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly.

```
if(!conditionOne && conditionTwo){
  //do nothing
} else {
  //do something
}
```

I hate having an empty code block for the if but I'm not sure of a better way to do this. This seems like the least amount of code without making it less simple with something like

```
if(!(!conditionOne && conditionTwo)){
```

This just looks odd to me but maybe this is better?

Or

```
if((!conditionOne && !conditionTwo) || (conditionOne && conditionTwo) || (conditionOne && !conditionTwo){
```

That seems more complicated to me.

```
conditionOne      conditionTwo          Outcome
False              True                  Do nothing
False              False                 Do something
True               True                  Do something
True               False                 Do something
```

What would be the best way to implement this?

Comment: `!(a && b)` <=> `!a || !b`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By [De-Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you're looking for

```
if(conditionOne || !conditionTwo) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).  It covers some important concepts.  For example:

`!(a && b)` is equivalent to `(!a || !b)`

and similarly

`!(a || b)` is equivalent to `(!a && !b)`